# Python - using ajax to post selected item from select list to Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am trying to write a small web application using Flask. But I have a question while creating selection list. For example, there are 2 selection lists in the web. The first one is "keyID" and second one is "fieldName". When user clicked an item in selection list "keyID" then a corresponding selection list "fieldName" appears.

Here's the HTML:

```
        <div class="control">
            <label for="keyid">KeyID of parking spots:</label><br>
            <select name ="keyidList" id="keyid_list" style="width: 400px">
                {% for keyid in keyIDs %}
                    <option value ="{{keyid}}">{{keyid}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select><br><br>
        </div>
        
        <div class="control">
            <label for="fieldname">FieldName of parking spots:</label><br>
            <select name ="fieldnameList" id="fieldname_list" style="width: 400px">
                {% for fieldname in fieldnames %}
                    <option value ="{{fieldname}}">{{fieldname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select><br><br>
        </div>
```

Javascript code in HTML file

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
  $(function(){
      var select_keyid = $('#keyid_list');
      var selected_keyid = select_keyid.val();

      select_keyid.on('change', function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
            'selected_keyid': selected_keyid,
            }),
            url: "{{ url_for('auth.get_fieldname_list') }}",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#fieldname").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      $("#fieldname").append('<option value="' +fieldname+ '">' + fieldname + '</option>');
                }
            }
         });
      });
    });
 </script>
</head>
```

And here's the Python Flask code

```
@auth.route('/get_fieldname_list', methods=['POST'])
def get_fieldname_list():
  req = request.json
  keyid = req.get('selected_keyid')
  fieldname = get_field_name_from_keyid(keyid)
  return fieldname
```

I personally think that, the problem is with ajax code but I don't know why and how to fix it. Any advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this line `var selected_keyid = select_keyid.val();` should be inside event handler else it will take only first value .

Comment: @Swati, thank you but for now it still doesn't work at all. Do you know anyway to debug javascript in html file? I am newbie with web dev

Comment: check your browser console if there are any error . Also do `console.log(selected_keyid)` inside your event handler see if value is showing or not (this you can see inside browser console) .